# Google maps api v2 key error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I recently changed my hard drive to my Pc and when I clone my project from github and add the google-play-services as a library I tried to open the google maps and I didn't get any error but nothing shown up. I can see only the zoom buttons and the my location icon. Do I have to regenerate the [google-map-api-key](/questions/tagged/google-map-api-key) for the new ssd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to get your currently generated key from `debug.keystore` folder and register it via the Google API Console, here is a blog post I wrote on how to do just that:

[Generating Google Map API V2 key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll have to regenerate your maps API key, as I gues you have a new certificate on your new hard drive. Use keytool to do that, like here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key